# Android PopUpWindow with two buttons, textView and TextEdit

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I have my app in which I touch a button and displays a popup window. Inside it is the following layout:

**popupip.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/popup_border" >
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dirección IP: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/dir_ip" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_ip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/nuevaip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/guardar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Guardar"
            android:onClick="guardarip" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/salir"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Salir" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Button `salir` is the dismiss button. Also I want to write some text in the textedit view, so when i touch `guardar` button it stores it in a string and put it in textview `ip`.
I also have the following code for the popup:

**Activity_main.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final Button botonip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ip);
    botonip.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
 = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
  .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupip, null);  
         final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
           popupView, 
           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

         Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.salir);
         btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  popupWindow.dismiss();
 }});     


         popupWindow.showAsDropDown(botonip, 50, -30);

}});                
}
```

my question is if can use more than one popupView.finViewById for the other elements in the popup or how can I handle the button, textView and TextEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may use popupView.findViewById() as many times as you would like, just like you can use findViewById() multiple times in an activity.